# Semantic UI Embed: How to know state change?

Tags: jquery, semantic-ui

Is there any way to trigger a callback method for state change event if I use Semantic UI Embed to play Youtube video?
I didn't find any information in Semantic UI documentation. Is it possible to use JQuery and pass callback methods at the time of calling embed()?

Answer (score 1):

If you have used it in div like this `<div class="ui embed"></div>`

```
$('.custom.example .ui.embed').embed({
  source      : 'youtube',
  id          : 'O6Xo21L0ybE',
  placeholder : '/images/bear-waving.jpg',
  autoplay: 'auto'
});
```

You can check official docs: https://semantic-ui.com/modules/embed.html#/settings

Comment: I want to know the change of state like end of video or stopping the video.

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing same problem now and after some research I came to the conclusion that's not possible at this moment (via Semantic-UI ofc). YT API's callbacks like **onPlay** or **onStop** haven't been implemented yet in Semantic.

Looking into semantic embed.js file, You can find:

`// NOT YET IMPLEMENTED
  api     : false,
  onPause : function() {},
  onPlay  : function() {},
  onStop  : function() {}`

Check yourself: [Semantic-Ui repo's link](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/blob/master/dist/components/embed.js#L700)

Maybe you found a solution?